Is pointwise convergence of MGFs at positive points enough to determine convergence in distribution?
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables and let $X$ be another random variable. Assume that the MGFs of $X_n$ converges pointwise to the MGF of $X$ at positive points. That is, for all $t > 0$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}M_{X_n}(t) = M_X(t).$$
Does it imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = X$ in distribution? I don't think it should be true, but I couldn't find a counter example.
